# How do I compare list item values in a code, then add them together to find what items are most likely going to produce a higher number?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

I am looking to compare 1 list to another list. Then instead of getting a true or false answer, I would be able to then go ahead and add those values together. I am fairly new to this and I understand dictionaries, but I am having a hard time finding resources that would point in the right direction.

List:

```
mle = {"Weapon" : "fist", "Damage" : 73, "Fire Rate" : 80, "Range" : 59, "Accuracy" : 72, "Recoil" : 79, "Mobility" : 54, "Handling" : 51}
```

I would like to then compare to this list here:

```
brassKnucles = {"Attachment" : "brass", "Damage" : 3, "Fire Rate" : 0, "Range" : 0, "Accuracy" : 3, "Recoil" : -2", "Mobility" : 5, "Handling" : 0}
```

I would like to add one item, Damage from "mle" to the damage of brassKnucles.

Conceptually I would do this

```
mle[2] + brassknucles[2]
```

Now while that is good, I have one more thing I want to do. I would like to add a third list.

```
rings = {"Attachment" : "rings", "Damage" : 1, "Fire Rate" : 0, "Range" : 0, "Accuracy" : 5, "Recoil" : -6", "Mobility" : 7, "Handling" : 0}
```

Now I need an if statement and its hard to figure out how I will write it, I want to compare brassknuckles and rings, before adding to mle.

I know how to write out what I want to do, I am just having a hard time being able to put it on screen.

I tried this

```
def damage():
global a1, a2, a3, a4, a5, br1, br2, smg1, smg2, smg3, sg1, lmg1, lmg2, lmg3, mr1, mr2, sr, mle
if damage = "Damage":
    return
# Compare the stats
while(0==0):
    if mle[2] == 73:
        Print(mle)
        if brassKnucles[2] > rings[2]
            print(mle[2] + brassKnucles[2]
        else
            print("weapon" + mle[2] + "Attachment" + rings[2])
        break
        
return
```

Am I doing this correctly or am I just completely wrong?

Comment: *I understand dictionaries*. Sorry, but I don't think you do. You cannot access dictonaries by an index (unless you make the key an index, which would be pointless, as you could use lists instead). Also what you describe as lists are dictionaries. Lists and dictionaries are both data structures but they work and are used very differently. Your trying to compare two dictionaries and try to aggregate the values whenever the keys match.

Comment: @Mushroomator Hello, I just saw your comment, I was wondering then if you could help me privately, I have a function that I have been working on for a few hours now, and the problem is that the code is telling me
"for k,v in assault.items():
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'items'" However when I try to use dictionary approach, it is telling me to do something called slices, I am not sure what approach to use.

Answer (score 0):

is this something you are looking for? In python with dictionaries you access the value via the key `brassKnuclesDMG = brassKnucles["Damage"]`

```
def damage():

    if damage == "Damage":
        return
    # Compare the stats
    while(True):
        if mle["Damage"] == 73:
            print(mle)
            if brassKnucles["Damage"] > rings["Damage"]:
                print(mle["Damage"] + brassKnucles["Damage"])
            else:
                print("weapon" + mle["Damage"] + "Attachment" + rings["Damage"])
            break
```

If you are interested this article can help you with the key (bu dum tss) concepts https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_dictionaries.asp

Comment: I am not sure if that is what I am looking for, I didnt know you can specify key values. The output needs to specify mle + attachment. The attachment would need to compare its values. Would I need to do this for all attachments or could I do this with a list for the program to sort through?

What I mean is, lets say i have a list of 5 attachments, can I compare them all to eachother in one line, or do i have to compare between each of them in multiple if statements

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what the else statement is trying to do, but essentially if brassknucles (i called it bs) sustained more damage than rings then you are adding mle's damage value to bs. The code to do that is:

```
if bs["Damage"] > rings["Damage"]:
    print(mle["Damage"] + bs["Damage"])
```

I am guessing your else statement would be to add mle damage to rings instead if the statement above is false. If so, see code below:

```
else: print(mle["Damage"] + rings["Damage"])
```

Answer (score 0):

First attempt for programming is tricky, so with patience, we perhaps can start with familiar ourselves with the basic operations for accessing a dictionary:

```
mle = {"Weapon" : "fist", "Damage" : 73, "Fire Rate" : 80, "Range" : 59, "Accuracy" : 72, "Recoil" : 79, "Mobility" : 54, "Handling" : 51}
brassKnucles = {"Attachment" : "brass", "Damage" : 3, "Fire Rate" : 0, "Range" : 0, "Accuracy" : 3, "Recoil" : -2, "Mobility" : 5, "Handling" : 0}
rings = {"Attachment" : "rings", "Damage" : 1, "Fire Rate" : 0, "Range" : 0, "Accuracy" : 5, "Recoil" : -6, "Mobility" : 7, "Handling" : 0}

print(mle["Damage"])
print(mle["Damage"]+brassKnucles["Damage"])
print(mle["Damage"]+brassKnucles["Damage"]+rings["Damage"])
```

Output:

```
73
76
77
```

to iter a dictionary

```
for k,v in mle.items():
    print(k,v)
```

Output:

```
Weapon fist
Damage 73
Fire Rate 80
Range 59
Accuracy 72
Recoil 79
Mobility 54
Handling 51
```

or

```
for k in mle:
    print(k,mle[k])
```

Output:

```
Weapon fist
Damage 73
Fire Rate 80
Range 59
Accuracy 72
Recoil 79
Mobility 54
Handling 51
```

Then try again to write what you want to process ;)

Comment: This was very helpful! I will be adding this to my script!
I am creating a script that is going to find specific items with the best comparison for each item type. This will reduce the amount of lines I have to write, thank you!